# how to change the style of a button on release outside of button boundaries

Tags: codenameone

I would like to make it so that a button highlights when it is pressed, and un-highlights (?) when it is released. Right now I have implemented the pressed part by overriding the pressed function in the subclass of Button, and the released part by overriding the two released functions. However, I have an issue that when you press the button, drag the mouse and release it outside of the Button, the button stays highlighted. I wanted to try doing the same thing by overriding dragFinished but this has not been working for me, so I am looking for another way.

```
@Override
public void pressed(){
    super.pressed();
        Style style = getParent().getStyle();
        style.setBorder(Border.createLineBorder(1, 1416152));
        updateParentStyle(style);
}

@Override
public void released(){
    super.released();
        Style style = getParent().getStyle();
        style.setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
        updateParentStyle(style);
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code what you've tried so far?

Comment: I added code but the above code actually already works... I was more of looking for a suggestion as to a new strategy I could take to handle the dragging and releasing issue, because I'm not too familiar with the entire API. I tried doing the exact same thing as above with pointerDragged, but it had no effect. I also tried it with dragFinished, but I have no access to that function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do that.

Just override the "Pressed" state of the button in [the theme](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/basics.html) to have a different border which is the "right way" or alternatively do what you did thru the style:

```
myButton.getPressedStyle().setBorder(Border.createLineBorder(1, 1416152));
myButton.getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
myButton.getSelectedStyle().setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
```